# Remove item in $_SESSION PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I tried to remove element in $_SESSION['cart_item'] but it didn't work, and this is my code insert records to array

```
$itemArray = array($itemcode1=>array('barcode'=>$_POST["barcode"],'code'=>$_POST["code"],'name'=>$_POST['itemname'], 'qty'=>$_POST["qty"],'cogs'=>$_POST["cogs"],'disc1'=>$disc1,'disc2'=>$disc2,'disc3'=>$disc3,'tglexp'=>$tglexp));


                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                {
                    if(in_array($itemcode1,$_SESSION["cart_item"])) 
                    {
                        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v)
                        {
                            if($itemcode == $k)
                            {
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["qty"] = $_POST["qty"];
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["cogs"] = $_POST["cogs"];
                            //$_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["discitem"] = $_POST["discitem"];
                            //$_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["unit"]= $productByCode[0]["itemunit"];
                            }
                        }
                    } else
                        {
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                        }
                } else 
                    {
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                    }


        }
```

and this is code to remove elemt from session

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) 
        {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) 
            {
                if($_GET["codetr"] == $k){
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);
                }

                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe `$_GET["codetr"] === $v` is correct or if not, maybe it never hits and never unset elements inside `$_["cart_item"]` you have to trace your variables.

Comment: can't work after i change variable

Comment: What's the error? please share errors for further assistance. changing `$k` with `$v` in `if($_GET["codetr"] == $k)` should not make any error at all.

Comment: check if `isset()` then `unset`

Comment: no error message, but the element still exist,

Comment: As with any troubleshooting, you can either start where it's broke, or start where it works...  To prove that the unset is being executed: Stick in a `die('works to here')`  after the closing brace of the `foreach` loop, and stick in `print "Matched 'codetr'";` just before `unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);`  If you get that, you know that the unset is indeed your problem.  If not,  look elsewhere. I really suspect the GET variable isn't what you think.

Comment: I usually do not use unset on session variable, I just make the session variable blank like this => $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k] ='';

Comment: I put a  statement like this : `code` echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ifff');></script> `code`, but nothing happen

Comment: You could use [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) tool to trace your code, and see if that line is a hit? if not you could check variables values to see what happens on that line or lines before it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for my question before:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){

                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k=>$v) 
                {

                    if($_GET["codetr"] == $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["code"]){
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);
                    }

                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: Exactly what I said, the thing is `$_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]` is same as `$v` so you could write it as `$v["code"]` which there is no way to find out for someone except yourself.